# Project moved from localhost to a Third Party Host: CodeIgniter Database Class not returning query results, but MySQLI does

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

**Using CodeIgniter 2.1.3**

I recently moved my website project from my localhost (apache server) to an online third party host.
But now, CodeIgniters Database-class can't seem to get any rows from the databse. The database.php config file is the same, everything else is the same! The only thing that changed was any changes that might come from moving my website project folder from my computer to another place (file paths, etc?). The EXACT SAME CODE works on my localhost, but it doesn't work when uploaded to the third party host.

From the below code I'm creating a string I will send to an Exception so that I can watch the results in the browser. The string is of two parts. The first part shows the results from the CI Database Class, then separated by a colon (:), then the second part is the result from the MySQLi query.
The CI Database part is always empty, but the MySQLi query part is filled with correct results.
This shows that the there is something wrong with the database class or the connection to the database, since the MySQLi example with the exact same query works.

What have I missed? This is REALLY frustrating. For three days I couldn't come up with a reason to why it might not work. I hope you can help!

```
//Test with CI Database Class

$this->load->database();
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM challenge');
$test = "CI Db Query: ";
foreach ($query->result() as $row)   //Always empty!!
{
 $test .= $row->title;
}
//Test with MySQLI
$test2= "MYSQLI Query: ";
$con=mysqli_connect("my_host","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$result = $con->query("SELECT * from challenge");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 $test2.= $row["title"];
}
throw new Exception($test. " : ". $test2); //For the exception to show in the browser as an Internal Error
```

This is my database.php config file, as you can see it's basically the same connection string.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'my_host';
$db['default']['username'] = 'my_user';
$db['default']['password'] = 'my_password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'my_db';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

The result is:

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'CI Db Query: : MYSQLI
>   Query: Title1Title2Title3

Comment: compare your local server settings with your hosting server settings.

Comment: What should I look for in those settings? Can you explain why CI Database Class doesn't work, but MySQLI does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the dbdriver to mysqli. I think different versions of mySQL require the other driver

Comment: I beat you to this answer, but this is exactly what was wrong. Good job, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that my third party host did not have the mysql extension, they only had mysqli. I changed to mysqli and now everything is working like a charm. Terribly hard to debug!